# Javascript onclick почему не работает? ('onclick' of null")

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var shareBtn = document.getElementById('#share');

  shareBtn.onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("#social");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.social-network {
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="share" class="product__share-btn">Share it!</a>
<div id="social" class="social-network"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не селектор

```
document.getElementById('share');
...
  var x = document.getElementById("social");
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Седьмой рабочий день за неделю.. , внимательность == null

Comment: Подскажите еще, почему не открывается с первого клика, а только с второго?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik Потому что изначально элемент невидим не из-за того, что у него явный (inline) `x.style.display === "none"`, a из-за класса `social-network`.